Does the Giuoco Pianissimo also include the Italian Four Knights or is the Giuoco Pianissimo only when White plays Pawn to c3?
I searched on Google and all websites say that the Giuoco Pianissimo is 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.d3. But after 4...Nf6, White has two options: c3 and Nc3. Does the Giuoco Pianissimo include both of them or only the first one? All websites seem to indicate that the Giuoco Pianissimo includes both of them, but IMHO it would make more sense to use the name "Giuoco Pianissimo" to refer only to the first one. Because these are two different openings, so they should have two different names. We already have a name for the second one, it's called the Italian Four Knights. If the name "Giuoco Pianissimo" includes both of them, then we wouldn't have a name to refer to the first one.

4.c3 is "Classical Variation", so maybe "Delayed Classical"? LiChess also files d3+c3 as "C54 Italian Game: Classical Variation, Giuoco Pianissimo". IMHO you are right, Sc3 and c3 setups should get a different name.
